# Presenting elements in the order they appear in XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt-1.0

I'm relatively new in XSLT and XMLs in general. 
I'm trying to be able to transform an XML file with sections that looks like this:

```
        <messageTypes>
        <id>EOL</id>
        <Headline>this is the headline of a message
        </Headline>
        <Description>1. This is the description of a message</Description>
        <infoTable>
            <fieldName>EOL</fieldName>
            <DTLink>
                <DTLinkL>string(3)</DTLinkL>
                <DTLinkT>string(3)</DTLinkT>
            </DTLink>
            <fieldSize>1</fieldSize>
            <fieldValue>0x42</fieldValue>
            <descriptionWithLink>
                <Description>it's the end of the world as we know it</Description>
                <XLink>
                    <XLinkL>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780145/inserting-images-from-xml-to-xsl-document
                    </XLinkL>
                    <XLinkT>here's a link for ye</XLinkT>
                </XLink>
                <SLink>
                    <SLinkL>header</SLinkL>
                    <SLinkT>This is also like this type of structure header</SLinkT>
                </SLink>
            </descriptionWithLink>
        </infoTable>
        <optionalElement id="Choice 1">
            <fieldName>option A</fieldName>
            <DTLink>
                <DTLinkL>string(4)</DTLinkL>
                <DTLinkT>string(4)</DTLinkT>
            </DTLink>
            <fieldSize>1</fieldSize>
            <fieldValue>0xdeadbeef</fieldValue>
            <descriptionWithLink>
                <Description>dead beef is dead beef</Description>
                <XLink>
                    <XLinkL>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780145/inserting-images-from-xml-to-xsl-document
                    </XLinkL>
                    <XLinkT>here's a link for ye</XLinkT>
                </XLink>
            </descriptionWithLink>
        </optionalElement>
        <infoTable>
            <fieldName>EOL</fieldName>
            <DTLink>
                <DTLinkL>string(2)</DTLinkL>
                <DTLinkT>string(2)</DTLinkT>
            </DTLink>
            <fieldSize>1</fieldSize>
            <fieldValue>0x42</fieldValue>
            <descriptionWithLink>
                <Description>it's the end of the world as we know it</Description>
                <XLink>
                    <XLinkL>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780145/inserting-images-from-xml-to-xsl-document
                    </XLinkL>
                    <XLinkT>here's a link for ye</XLinkT>
                </XLink>
                <SLink>
                    <SLinkL>middle</SLinkL>
                    <SLinkT>This is also like this type of structure middle</SLinkT>
                </SLink>
            </descriptionWithLink>
        </infoTable>
```

To something that will able to express this:

[image: this is what I want]

The "if" breakups of the table section so that 
1. The fact that you can either have one element here (which would lead to the more common type of message) or another element (which would lead to a different but rarer type of element).
2. Attention is drawn to the fact that the possible section detailed in in OptionalElement is not a common occurrence but can happen.

The XSL I built looks like this:

```
<h1>Messages</h1>
                <xsl:for-each
                    select="m:SectionMessageTypes/m:messageTypes">
                    <xsl:variable name="MessageID" select="m:id" />
                    <h3 id="{$MessageID}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="m:Headline" />
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="m:Description" />
                    </p>
                    <table width="80%" border="2" cellpadding="5">
                        <tr bgcolor="#87CEFA">
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Type</td>
                            <td>Size</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Description</td>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="m:infoTable">
                            <xsl:variable name="MessageID" select="m:id" />
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="m:fieldName='header'">
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="#header">Header</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldName" />
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                        select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                    <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldSize" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldValue" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:Description" />
                                    <br />
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="XLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkL" />
                                        <a href="{$XLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="DLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkL" />
                                        <a href="#{$DLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="MLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkL" />
                                        <a href="#{$MLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                        <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="SLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkL" />
                                        <a href="#{$SLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                    <table width="80%" border="2" cellpadding="5">
                        <tr bgcolor="#E0FFFF">
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Type</td>
                            <td>Size</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Description</td>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="m:optionalElement">
                            <tr>
                                <img src="./Flowchart_condition_symbol.svg.png" width="42"
                                    height="42" />
                                <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="m:fieldName='header'">
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="#header">Header</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldName" />
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                        select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                    <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldSize" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldValue" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:Description" />
                                    <br />
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="XLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkL" />
                                        <a href="{$XLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="DLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkL" />
                                        <a href="#{$DLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="MLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkL" />
                                        <a href="#{$MLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                        <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="SLinkV"
                                            select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkL" />
                                        <a href="#{$SLinkV}">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkT" />
                                        </a>
                                        <br />
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
```

Which makes the HTML page look like this:
[image]

As you can see....OptionalElement does not appear between the two InfoTable elements.

Is there a non-css way of doing this?

This is a project for work and I don't have to time frame to go into CSS just yet, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Change the inner `for-each` loop to

```
<xsl:for-each select="m:infoTable | m:optionalElement">
```

Then the `m:optionalElement` will be processed between both `m:infoTable` elements - in document order.

In the loop you have to differentiate between those two if the processing differs (it does). For example with

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="self::m:infoTable">
        ...
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="self::m:optionalElement">
        <h1>OPTION</h1>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: That's OK, I figured it out

Comment: If my answer was helpful, it would be common to accept it ;-)

Comment: I don't know if it was, I didn't try it, I tried what I did. What I did worked. Not saying yours might not work, just that I can't verify it.

Comment: If you found a solution by yourself, that's ok. Good luck with your further endeavours.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

First, in the XSD add optionalElement to your infoTable and another, new element called rowType:

```
    <xs:element name="infoTable">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="fieldName" type="xs:string"
                minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="fieldType" type="xs:string"
                minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element ref="DTLink" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="fieldSize" type="xs:string"
                minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="fieldValue" type="xs:string"
                minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element ref="descriptionWithLink" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="rowType" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="optionalElement" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="Example" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Then, create each infoTable element like so:

```
            <infoTable>
            <rowType>else</rowType>
            <optionalElement>
                CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION is not set in either
                server-caps or client-caps
            </optionalElement>
            <fieldName>Password</fieldName>
            <DTLink>
                <DTLinkL>NullTerminatedString</DTLinkL>
                <DTLinkT>NullTerminatedString</DTLinkT>
            </DTLink>
            <fieldValue>varies</fieldValue>
            <descriptionWithLink>
                <Description>Plain text password. Used by older clients and
                    servers
                </Description>
            </descriptionWithLink>
        </infoTable>
        <infoTable>
            <rowType>data</rowType>
            <fieldName>DB Name</fieldName>
            <DTLink>
                <DTLinkL>NullTerminatedString</DTLinkL>
                <DTLinkT>NullTerminatedString</DTLinkT>
            </DTLink>
            <fieldSize>Length </fieldSize>
            <fieldValue>.</fieldValue>
            <descriptionWithLink>
                <Description>The database name to connect to. DB Name should be
                    taken from this field. Value is UTF-8 encoded.
                </Description>
            </descriptionWithLink>
        </infoTable>
        <infoTable>
        <rowType>if</rowType>
            <optionalElement>message contains more data</optionalElement>
                <fieldName>Character Set</fieldName>
                <DTLink>
                    <DTLinkL>int(2)</DTLinkL>
                    <DTLinkT>int(2)</DTLinkT>
                </DTLink>
                <fieldValue>2</fieldValue>
                <descriptionWithLink>
                    <Description>The value is ignored. This have been proven in tests
                        against 5.1.23. In 5.7 the field doesn't arrive. Further research
                        is needed to identify if UUT information presents in the message
                    </Description>
                </descriptionWithLink>
        </infoTable>
```

Then, in the XSL do a:

```
                            <xsl:for-each select="m:infoTable">
                            <xsl:variable name="MessageID" select="m:id" />
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="m:rowType='header'">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5">
                                            <a href="#header">Header</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="m:rowType='if'">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#E0FFFF" colspan="5">
                                            if {
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:optionalElement" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldName" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                                select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                            <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldSize" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldValue" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:Description" />
                                            <br />
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="XLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkL" />
                                                <a href="{$XLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="DLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$DLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="MLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$MLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="SLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$SLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="f8ffff" colspan="5"> }</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="m:rowType='else'">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#E0FFFF" colspan="5">
                                            else {
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:optionalElement" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldName" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                                select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                            <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldSize" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldValue" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:Description" />
                                            <br />
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="XLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkL" />
                                                <a href="{$XLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="DLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$DLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="MLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$MLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="SLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$SLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="f8ffff" colspan="5"> }</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldName" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                                select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                            <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldSize" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="m:fieldValue" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:Description" />
                                            <br />
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="XLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkL" />
                                                <a href="{$XLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:XLink/m:XLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="DLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$DLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DLink/m:DLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="MLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$MLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:MLink/m:MLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="DTLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$DTLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:DTLink/m:DTLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink">
                                                <xsl:variable name="SLinkV"
                                                    select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkL" />
                                                <a href="#{$SLinkV}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of
                                                        select="m:descriptionWithLink/m:SLink/m:SLinkT" />
                                                </a>
                                                <br />
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
```

The result is, indeed:

[image]